# Set FAB Border color

Tags: android, colors, floating-action-button

I want to make a Floating Action Button (FAB) (from the design support library) with black background and borders having the same color as my primary color.

I have read the answer by @vipul_asri shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33008431/3520621).

But, when I replace the "transparent" color to a black one (or any other) this changes the background of my FAB to the `backgroundTint` color which also doesn't have a border.

Is it hard to put borders on a FAB button? Does anyone know how is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change android design support library FAB Button border color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005929/how-to-change-android-design-support-library-fab-button-border-color)