# How to change Floating Button border color?

Tags: android, xml, styles, floating-action-button

I want to change the floating button border color. I have try the code from multiple sources but didn't get satisfying answer. Please tell me is it possible to change the border color of floating button in android. Looking forward to get positive response. Thanks

Code:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/response_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:background="@drawable/ring"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_fab_calendar_add"
    android:tint="@color/white"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:rippleColor="@color/gray"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried this solution? Basicaly creates a new shape and sets the background of FAB. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005929/how-to-change-android-design-support-library-fab-button-border-color/33008431#33008431

Comment: @MustafaBerkayMutlu yes I have try this solution but not working on my side.