# White border for FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, floating-action-button

I need to create a FAB with white border and filled with a solid color (blue or grey).

**xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/myFab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

[image]

I tried the accepted solution suggested in [How to change android design support library FAB Button border color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005929/how-to-change-android-design-support-library-fab-button-border-color). But did not work (did not add border).

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include what you mean by "it did not work"

Comment: @AjilO.What I meant is, it did not add the border. Please see the project I created with this change - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxEa4zO6gm2FT1hkemtfUC1vSW8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rl_content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_white_border"
        android:padding="3dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:fabSize="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

background for the floating action button

```
in the drawable fab_border.xml

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="2"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This solution works fine in phones. But in tablets it add additional padding.

Comment: Issue was not in tablets. In pre-lollipop OS, there is an additional padding for FAB. This can be fixed by adding 
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:pressedTranslationZ="0dp"
 for FloatingActionButton. SO I am accepting this answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Notice that the background drawable is set for the surrounding linear layout, not the fab itself. Otherwise it wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

`drawable` circle_white_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="2"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

Floating Action Button in layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/myFab"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_white_border"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help my friend!. This solution didn't work for me. Please find the attached project with the your solution implemented - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxEa4zO6gm2FT1hkemtfUC1vSW8

Answer (score 0):

You can create this programmatically as:

```
ImageButton iV = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myFab);
    int strokeWidth = 5;
    int strokeColor = Color.parseColor("#03dc13");
    int fillColor = Color.parseColor("#ff0000");
    GradientDrawable gD = new GradientDrawable();
    gD.setColor(fillColor);
    gD.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
    gD.setStroke(strokeWidth, strokeColor);
    iV.setBackground(gD);
```

Change the colors as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **foreground** attribute therefore **extra view** and  **nested layouts** won't needed:

```
<style name="bookingButton">
    <item name="android:src">@mipmap/fab_icon</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/fabDim</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/fabDim</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">right|end|bottom</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">@dimen/fabMargin</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">center</item>
    <item name="elevation">@dimen/fabElevation</item>
    <item name="pressedTranslationZ">@dimen/fabPressedTranslationZ</item>
    <item name="android:foreground">@drawable/circle_border</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/colorThird</item>
    <item name="borderWidth">@dimen/zero</item>
</style>
```

And **circle_border.xml**:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
    <stroke android:width="@dimen/strokeSecond" android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```