# How to add a border in floating action button

Tags: android, android-studio, border, floating-action-button

I have a floating button with full white background tint and an image source. I want to surround it with a grey border. I don't find any way to do so. Please help.

I've just created a normal FAB.

Here is the XML code of my button.

```
      <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:src="@drawable/addvideo"
        app:backgroundTint="#fff"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:id="@+id/myFab"
        />
```

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005929/how-to-change-android-design-support-library-fab-button-border-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you can do these steps:

- First define a custom shape in a new **xml** file in your **drawable** directory:

**fab_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="2"
    android:useLevel="false" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <!-- here set the width and color of your border -->
    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</shape>
```

- Then wrap your FAB inside a layout and set the custom drawable file to be the background of the layout. Here you need to give this wrapper layout a **padding** with the same size as your border:

**your main layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- the wrapper layout having a padding with the size of your border -->
    <!-- and background set to the custom drawable file -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fabWrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/fab_background"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/myFab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="center"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            android:src="@drawable/addvideo"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

something old but it can be useful for beginners, you can use

To remove border color can use:

```
app:borderWidth="0dp"
```

To change border color:

```
app:borderWidth="2dp"
app:backgroundTint="#F44336"
```

An example:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:borderWidth="2dp"
                app:backgroundTint="#F44336"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_select_image_white"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_500"/>
```