# How to add border in Floating action button in Android

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I was trying to build something like the below image:

[image]

Here is my xml code:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_scan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/vector_nav_qr_scanner"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar" />
```

I was searching a lot but couldn't figure out how can I add the light blue background with a white circle border and also an icon in the center. Can any one help?

Comment: You can check this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53860591/how-to-add-a-border-in-floating-action-button). Thank you.

Comment: @LalremLianBTlung I see its a long process, doesn't it have any simple workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="#B1E4F6"               //inner background color
    android:src="@drawable/scan"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/white"              //outer background color (border color)
    app:borderWidth="8dp"
    app:maxImageSize="16dp"                        //inner icon size
    app:tint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />    //inner icon color
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
app.strokeColor = "#000033"
app.strokeWidth = "3dp"
```

in your floating action button xml..

for example:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_scan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/vector_nav_qr_scanner"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar"
        app:strokeColor = "#000033"
        app:strokeWidth = "3dp" />
```

edit: app:strokewidth and app:strokeColor is working for ExtendedFloatingActionButton. Sorry, that's my fault.
You can use

```
app:borderWidth="4dp" in stead of app:strokeWidth = "3dp". remove strokeColor. there showes little border.
```

i hope it will help you.
please let me know if it doesn't work.

**OR**
define custom shape in drawable folder

fab_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="2"
    android:useLevel="false" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <!-- here set the width and color of your border -->
    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</shape>
```

then wrap your FloatingActionButton with a layout. use fab_bg.xml file in layout's background.
for example:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fabWrapperId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/fab_bg"
        android:padding="5dp">

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_scan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/vector_nav_qr_scanner"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar"
            app:fabSize="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

NB: make sure your stroke width from fab_bg and layout padding keep the same.

Comment: I didn't make any difference!

Comment: @Reyjohn Replace app:strokeWidth  to app:borderWidth .  remove app:strokeColor. see my edited ans.

Comment: I can see a bit change but not getting the expected output either.

Comment: @Reyjohn yeah, I know, if you want  , then add some drawable xml file for background.

Comment: @Reyjohn now have a look at the edited answer, below "OR" you can find what you expected.